# How to export a txt file into csv with python?

Tags: python, csv, text

I have got a txt file like in this format:

```
Monday, Jul 24
8:45 apple 1    
school
ball
dog
8:50 poirot 2   
rouge
chien   
chat
8:55 football 3
asroma
juventus  
inter
```

How can i put these values into a csv with ignoring the first row (Monday, Jul 24) and insert the actual date in every rows?. I need this format:

```
A1 Monday, Jul 24
B1:8:45 apple 1   B2:school B3:ball    B4:dog    B5:ACTUALLY DATE
C1:8:50 poirot 2  C2:rouge  C3:chien   C4:chat   C5:ACTUALLY DATE
etcetc..
```

So i want to place them in this format.
Here my actually code:

```
import urllib2
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import re

#def to_2d(l,n):
#    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

with open('air.txt', 'r') as f:
    x = f.read()
print x

req_text = x.split('Test')[1: -1]

data = []
for text in req_text:
    text = text.split('\n', 1)[1]
    for line in text.strip().splitlines():
        data.append([line])

#maindatatable = to_2d(data, 4)

with open('output.csv', "wb") as f:
    output = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')
    output.writerows(data)

f.close()
```

I tried with the to_2d(l,n) but it isn't work, any idea how can i reach this format with the actually date? [Python 2.7]

Updated code, still not working:

```js
import urllib2
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import re

def to_2d(l,n):
    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
 
with open('air.txt', 'r') as f:
    x = f.read()
print x

req_text = x.split('Load')[1: -1]

data = []
for text in req_text:
    text = text.split('\n', 1)[1]
    for line in text.strip().splitlines():
        data.append([line])

#maindatatable = to_2d(data, 4)

from string import ascii_uppercase as LETTERS
with open('air.txt') as f, open('output.csv', 'wb') as g:
    actual_date = f.readline().strip()
    while True:
        first_line = f.readline().strip()
        if not first_line: 
            break
        second_line = f.readline().strip()
        third_line = f.readline().strip()
        fourth_line = f.readline().strip()
        the_time, noun, number = first_line.split(' ')
        number = int(number)
        letter = LETTERS[number]
        new_line = '%s1:%s %s %s %s2:%s %s3:%s %s4:%s %s5:%s' % (letter, the_time, noun, number, letter, second_line, letter, third_line, letter, fourth_line, letter, actual_date)
        print (new_line)




f.close()
```

Comment: This is not a constructive answer,this is an unnecessary answer, it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Your given Format isn't valid CSV, has to be equal Count of Columns. What do you mean with _**actually date**_, the System Date the Script is running?

Answer (score 0):

This script just prints the output lines rather than writing them to the output csv file. However, that would be an easy modification for you to make. Notice too that (a) a maximum of 25 lines can be written in this way because there are only 25 letters from 'B' to 'Z'; (b) if that first line in your sample output file were to be written to the csv file then it would not be valid input to pandas.

The script works by reading the first line and saving its contents as `actual_date` for use in output lines. Then it reads four lines at a time for use in creating single output lines.

```
>>> from string import ascii_uppercase as LETTERS
>>> with open('air.txt') as f, open('output.csv', 'wb') as g:
...     actual_date = f.readline().strip()
...     while True:
...         first_line = f.readline().strip()
...         if not first_line: 
...             break
...         second_line = f.readline().strip()
...         third_line = f.readline().strip()
...         fourth_line = f.readline().strip()
...         try:
...             the_time, noun, number = first_line.split(' ')
...         except:
...             print ('invalid input: ', first_line)
...             quit(2)
...         number = int(number)
...         letter = LETTERS[number]
...         new_line = '%s1:%s %s %s %s2:%s %s3:%s %s4:%s %s5:%s' % (letter, the_time, noun, number, letter, second_line, letter, third_line, letter, fourth_line, letter, actual_date)
...         print (new_line)
...         
B1:8:45 apple 1 B2:school B3:ball B4:dog B5:Monday, Jul 24
C1:8:50 poirot 2 C2:rouge C3:chien C4:chat C5:Monday, Jul 24
D1:8:55 football 3 D2:asroma D3:juventus D4:inter D5:Monday, Jul 24
```

Comment: I updated my question with your code, but it isn't working.
Error message: "he_time, noun, number = first_line.split(' ')
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack" 

Is there any other solution which one i can read more line, because 25 lines is not enough

Comment: To read more lines: After lines with B, C, D, etc, up to Z what would you want to have?

Comment: To diagnose the fault in the input use the edit code, with the try ... except construct.